# How to test for a positive or negative slope coefficient in regression models?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Consider the simple linear model:

$\vec Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 \vec X +\vec \varepsilon$

When I have read up on discussions about the different statistical tests that can be run on the model's slope coefficient $\beta_1$, I have exclusively seen the following null hypothesis / alternative hypothesis set up:

\begin{align} &H_0: \beta_1 =0 \\&H_a:\beta_1 \neq 0 \end{align}

With this particular test, there is then a $t$ statistic whose formula is given as $\beta_1$ divided by the standard error of $\beta_1$.

My question is **what if I was instead interested in the following null hypothesis**:

\begin{align} &H_0: \beta_1 \leq0 \\&H_a:\beta_1 \gt0 \end{align}

How exactly would I carry this out?

Is it possible to simply construct confidence intervals around $\beta_1$ (at a particular significance level) and if my resulting interval $(\beta_1-\delta,\beta_1+\delta)$ is strictly positive, I can then conclude that $\beta_1$ must be a positive number (as opposed to simply a non-zero number, which is what the prior hypothesis test would have provided us with)?

Comment: In *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*, by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer, Section 11.5, the authors lay out typical inferences such as $H_0: \beta_i=\beta_{i0}$ versus $H_a:\beta_i>\beta_{i0}$ or $H_a:\beta_i<\beta_{i0}$ or $H_a:\beta_i\not=\beta_{i0}.$ The test statistic is the same in all three cases, the rejection region changes. It's a fairly standard $t$ test in all three cases. Would one of these hypotheses match your research question?

Comment: Completely coincidentally, I just posted an answer.  You can find it in the middle of https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/572198/919.  Look at the three short paragraphs beginning "The null hypothesis..." preceding the first figure.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the input - I read your post but am having difficulties understanding how to implement your algorithm. AdrianKeister's response has given me further pause, as well. I was always under the impression that the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis, when unioned, had to cover the whole space of possibilities. For example, $H_0: \beta_1 \leq 0$ and $H_a: \beta_1 \gt 0$ clearly cover all cases for $\beta_1 \in \mathbb R$. However, $H_0: \beta_1 =0$ and $H_a:\beta_1 \gt 0$ do not cover all cases. Is that a problem?

Comment: First, that's not relevant to my post, because I use the first formulation.  Second, it's not a problem because the test in the second case is tantamount to the test in the first case.  Read about the difference between two-sided and one-sided tests for more information; but intuitively, when $\beta_1\lt 0$ it's even *less* likely the data will reject the hypothesis that $\beta_1=0.$ As far as implementing the algorithm goes, it amounts to halving the reported p-value and optionally subtracting it from $1:$ which part is causing difficulties in implementation?